# Linear Algebra - QF correct coefficient matrix?

Tags: quadratic-forms

Right, so I've completed the square of a quadratic form:

$$ q(x) = x_1^2 - 4x_1x_2 + 6x_1x_3 + 5x_2^2 - 10x_2x_3 + 11x_3^2$$

I found the coefficient matrix to be:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & -2 & 3 \\
        0 & -1 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

So solving for $$ D = P^tAP$$

I keep getting:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & -2 & 5 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Why do I keep getting -2 where it should be 0? Maybe a possible miscalculation somewhere or maybe I completed the squares wrong or something...?

Comment: the middle row of your "coefficient matrix" should be $0 \; \; \; 1 \; \; \; 1$ rather than the  $0 \; \; \; -1 \; \; \; 1$ you typed

Comment: I replied further down :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens that the "diagonal matrix" can be taken to be the identity matrix, expressed as quadratic forms:
$$(x-2y+3z)^2 +(y+z)^2 + z^2 = x^2 + 5 y^2 + 11 z^2 -10 yz + 6 zx - 4 xy  $$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 2 & 3 \\ 
 - 2 & 5 &  - 5 \\ 
3 &  - 5 & 11 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q =    \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D =    \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 3 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
3 & 1 & 11 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q =    \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 2 & 3 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D =    \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 &  - 5 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q =    \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 2 & 3 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D =    \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 5 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 2 & 3 \\ 
 - 2 & 5 &  - 5 \\ 
3 &  - 5 & 11 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 &  - 5 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
3 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 2 & 3 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 2 & 3 \\ 
 - 2 & 5 &  - 5 \\ 
3 &  - 5 & 11 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I only want to revert it purely algebraic from the completed square form back to the original quadratic form:

$$(x_1 - 2x_2 + 3x_3)^2 -/+ (x_2 + x_3)^2 + 3x_3^2$$

then we get either:

$$x_1^2 + 3x_2^2 + 11x_3^2 - 4x_1x_2 + 6x_1x_3 - 14x_2x_3$$

Or

$$x_1^2 + 5x_2^2 + 13x_3^2 - 4x_1x_2 + 6x_1x_3 - 10x_2x_3$$

We see that I don't fully get the original quadratic form.
So unless there is some little detail I've missed that gets you the coefficient matrix you got which is obviously correct then maybe it's something during the completing the squares method I'm not fully grasping?

Comment: This suggests that you got as far as correctly writing an acceptable first term $(x_1 - 2 x_2 + 3 x_3)^2$ but then got the wrong subtraction $  x_1^2 - 4x_1x_2 + 6x_1x_3 + 5x_2^2 - 10x_2x_3 + 11x_3^2 - (x_1 - 2 x_2 + 3 x_3)^2.$ What is the correct subtraction?

Comment: The correct subtraction if I understood it correctly should be: $$-x_2^2 - 2x_2x_3 - x_3^2 = - (x_2 + x_3)^2$$, is this always a safe way to confirm you have completed the square correctly?

Comment: I do not know what you are doing. The exact subtraction I wrote in comment above is equal to $x_2^2 + 2 x_2 x_3 + 2 x_3^2.$ Is there a book from which you are studying?

Comment: And thanks for helping me out, I've noticed you always reply to my questions :)

Comment: My teacher wrote the book although I'm not sure if he wrote it completely himself or if he just borrowed from another book, nontheless they barely cover this process in the book which is why I'm confused...but yes sorry you're right, I forgot the minus sign...but I know get the same as you did.

Comment: If you are going in the "completing the square" direction, when the coefficient of $x_1^2$ is $1,$ then we pick coefficients $B,C$ so that $(x_1 + B x_2 + C x_3)^2$ also agrees as far as the $x_1 x_2$ coefficient and the $x_1 x_3$ coefficient. The remaining things no longer have any $x_1$ terms, they are something of type $D x_2^2 + E x_2 x_3 + F x_3^2.$ In this case we got lucky because my $D=1.$  I have put a good deal of work into the matrix method I displayed because students appear to make mistakes in the "completing the square" method, which is nevertheless not really difficult.